# How to get realtime graph using google charts?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I am python desktop application developer but I found google- charts quite easy to pick and work with for my IOT project, I wanted to know if it is possible to have a realtime graph that has data fed from sensors.

I want a line graph something like [EPOCH](http://epochjs.github.io/epoch/real-time/#line) has ,

I have tried this [page](http://phant.io/graphing/google/2014/07/07/graphing-data/#getting-started) but it doesnt look realtime, I want temperature / humidity/ rain/ moisture update to be displayed on a web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['scatter']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  var contador = 0;
  function fill(chart,options){
        var json_prepared = new Array();        
      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/data.php',
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function(res) {
        // console.log(res);
        console.log("success");
        for (var i = res.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var ano = res[i][0];
            var mes = res[i][1];
            var dia = res[i][2];
            var hora = res[i][3];
            var fecha = new Date(ano,mes,dia);
            var elemento  = new Array(fecha,hora);
            json_prepared.push(elemento);
        }
    })
     .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log("complete");
    });
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Alertas');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Alertas');
    console.log(json_prepared);
         data.addRows(json_prepared);
        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Scatter.convertOptions(options));
        console.log('actualizado');
  }
  function drawChart () {
    contador++;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/data.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
    })
    .done(function(res) {
        var json_prepared = new Array();        
        console.log("success");
        for (var i = res.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var ano = res[i][0];
            var mes = res[i][1];
            var dia = res[i][2];
            var hora = res[i][3];
            var fecha = new Date(ano,mes,dia);
            var elemento  = new Array(fecha,hora);
            json_prepared.push(elemento);
        }
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Datas');
        console.log(json_prepared);
         data.addRows(json_prepared);
    var options = {
      width: 800,
      height: 650,
      chart: {
        title: 'Students\' Final Grades',
        subtitle: 'based on hours studied'
      },    
      hAxis: {
             title: "Date",
      },
      vAxis: {
        title: "Houar"         
      }
    };
    var chart = new google.charts.Scatter(document.getElementById('scatterchart_material'));
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'error', function (googleError) {
        console.log(googleError);
  google.visualization.errors.removeError(googleError.id);
  document.getElementById("error_msg").innerHTML = "Message removed = '" + googleError.message + "'";}); chart.draw(data, google.charts.Scatter.convertOptions(options));setInterval(function(){
        console.log(chart);
        fill(chart,options);
    },3000); })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log("complete");
    });
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

you could use `$.ajax` and `setInterval` to *simulate* realtime

using a setup similar to the following,
this would draw the chart every 10 seconds...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {

    drawChart();
    setInterval(drawChart, 10000);

    function drawChart() {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'get sensor data',
        type: 'get',
        success: function (json) {
          var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(json);
          var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
          chart.draw(data);
        }
      });
    }

  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

Comment: I am thinking to populate table to data.sparkfun.com and fetch it from there on my web page, so I think I can do call to fetch on load as well after certain interval so graphs keeps on refreshing not the whole page

Comment: sounds good, above should refresh chart only, on load and interval

Answer (score 1):

One option would to use trigger an event when the data is updated. If your IOT project supports pushing data (rather than fetching via ajax for example) then that's all you need. If you use a realtime database such as Firebase then it's even simpler.

Using global variables in this example, if you use a JS framework it may have other methods of tracking data. After initialising the chart as normal, you could update it with something like this:

```
// Your IOT project could trigger a javascript event,
// or plug it into Firebase and listen for changes.
onEvent("newData", function(data) {
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task',     data.Task],
    ['Work',     data.Work],
    ['Eat',      data.Eat],
    ['Commute',  data.Commute],
    ['Watch TV', data.Tv],
    ['Sleep',    data.Sleep]
   ]);
   chart.draw(data, options);
});
```